# RaspBerry Pi 4 Python Update hash sum mismatch

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to update my Raspberry Pi and have been stuck for a while with the following error:

```
pihole@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgtk-3-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-pip-whl python3-pip
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,002 kB/2,339 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python-pip-whl all 20.3.4-4+rpt1+deb11u1 [2,002 kB]
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python-pip-whl all 20.3.4-4+rpt1+deb11u1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:815c0bcf877e8f8222bb24b3081fba7fcfdb23a29a60c9068a9eadb226b64fe7
   - SHA1:07474132bc338878c28a5f80ba1d0fdfdf038fbb [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2b2a9327ce48685b902cb4c18fe2270c [weak]
   - Filesize:2001632 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:00e64316dae28ab47841a78c214d6c661ffa30ec40c0350c9e8d26fa70bd427d
   - SHA1:78cd0e78c02753def41ba7a297f6c5f79e0067e4 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:794df4fc23cd99d6b0fbc1229a4e2666 [weak]
   - Filesize:8027 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 12 Oct 2022 03:22:25 +0000
Fetched 8,027 B in 2s (3,454 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://10.0.0.1:82/app/content_filter/warning/index/aHR0cDovL2FyY2hpdmUucmFzcGJlcnJ5cGkub3JnL2RlYmlhbi9wb29sL21haW4vcC9weXRob24tcGlwL3B5dGhvbi1waXAtd2hsXzIwLjMuNC00JTJicnB0MSUyYmRlYjExdTFfYWxsLmRlYg../VmlydXMgb3IgYmFkIGNvbnRlbnQgZGV0ZWN0ZWQuIEhldXJpc3RpY3MuQnJva2VuLkV4ZWN1dGFibGU.  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:815c0bcf877e8f8222bb24b3081fba7fcfdb23a29a60c9068a9eadb226b64fe7
    - SHA1:07474132bc338878c28a5f80ba1d0fdfdf038fbb [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2b2a9327ce48685b902cb4c18fe2270c [weak]
    - Filesize:2001632 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:00e64316dae28ab47841a78c214d6c661ffa30ec40c0350c9e8d26fa70bd427d
    - SHA1:78cd0e78c02753def41ba7a297f6c5f79e0067e4 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:794df4fc23cd99d6b0fbc1229a4e2666 [weak]
    - Filesize:8027 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 12 Oct 2022 03:22:25 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

And can't get it to work, any help is welcome.  Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.